# Weird error with compiling, since switching to Yosemite

Tags: macos, xcode6

I switched to Yosemite, and whenever I try to run my program, I get this error:

> ```
> OS X deployment target '11.0' for architecture 'x86_64' and variant 'normal' is greater than the maximum value '10.9' for the OS X 10.9 SDK.
> Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
> ```

I really don't know what to do, tried to look for these kind of errors didn't find any good solution, I tried to reinstall XCode (5.0.2), nothing changed.

Comment: What is your [Deployment target](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26076930/1454048) set to?

Comment: Thanks, changed the Deployment Target to 10.9! Sorry for that "stupid" question, thanks a lot